# Is there a way to salvage a partition table that was automatically edited by windows?

Tags: partition, windows, restore

I tried upgrading to windows 10 and expected it to overwrite the bootloader, but it screwed up the partition table as well. So I'm wondering if there's any way to recover the linux installation.

Here's an excerpt from the Boot repair log:

```
============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 480.1 GB, 480103981056 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 58369 cylinders, total 937703088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       718,847       716,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             718,848   546,152,716   545,433,869   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         546,154,496   547,074,047       919,552  27 Hidden NTFS (Recovery Environment)
/dev/sda4         547,076,094   937,701,375   390,625,282   5 Extended
/dev/sda5     ? 1,872,973,105 5,529,806,839 3,656,833,735  fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda6     ? 2,139,002,515 2,179,868,678    40,866,164  23 Unknown

/dev/sda5 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda
the logical partition /dev/sda5 is not contained in the extended partition /dev/sda4
/dev/sda5 overlaps with /dev/sda6
/dev/sda6 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda
the logical partition /dev/sda6 is not contained in the extended partition /dev/sda4
```

Note that sda5 is several times larger than the total possible sectors and it begins after the end of the drive.

Theoretically if I knew the start and end sectors of the logical partitions, could i rewrite the table?

Here's the full boot repair log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12149066/

Here's the testdisk log: https://cryptbin.com/5yN9qY#9bfdeae9ce2eff44f7b2cc142ba710a8

I really wish I had a more precise question to ask other than "can anyone help me?" but this is beyond my experience, and I don't even know what I'm trying to ask. Thanks in advance